# System Sound Services Won't play audio when connected to a car's bluetooth

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, sdk, system

I am using System Sound Services to play audio in my application
It works perfectly when using speakers, headphones or even a dock USB car stereo connection.
However when the phone is connected to a car bluetooth system the audio won't play.

I imagine that since it's connected to a bluetooth device the System Sound Services would try to send to the audio through Bluetooth.

Does anyone knows how I can prevent the audio route from trying to send to the sound through Bluetooth?

Here's the code I am using:

```
CFURLRef        soundFileURLRef;
SystemSoundID   soundFileObject;

CFBundleRef mainBundle;
mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle ();

// Get the URL to the sound file to play
soundFileURLRef  =  CFBundleCopyResourceURL (
                                                 mainBundle,
                                                 CFSTR ("Alert6"),
                                                 CFSTR ("aif"),
                                                 NULL
                                                 );

// Create a system sound object representing the sound file
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (
                                      soundFileURLRef,
                                      &soundFileObject
                                      );

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundFileObject);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the output to the internal speaker

```
UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker; // lets the system sounds come out of the speaker
OSStatus err = AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute, sizeof(audioRouteOverride), &audioRouteOverride);
if (err != noErr) {
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: Hi Coney.  I have tried this before and it does not work.
Should it also override the sound output when connecting a headphone or just a bluetooth?